# PHP $_POST["password"]

Tags: php, html, session, post

I'm trying to build a login page, where the user enters a password, and if it matches "secret" word, the user can explore 3 options.
I've tried with session_start(), and enabling an "authenticate" in order to be able to view the 3 options, but every time I click on them, they take me back to the main page. What am I doing wrong?
P.S I want to be able to hide the login form after I authenticate successfully.
Any help is highly appreciated.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>
    </title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
$entries = array(
    array(
        'stage' => 'Stage One',
        'plan' => 'To begin your plan, you must first Blackmail a Town Mascot. This will cause the world to sit up and take notice, stunned by your arrival. Who is this Ripe Bastard? Where did they come from? And why do they look so good as a Dark Gunslinger?',
    ),
    array(
        'stage' => 'Stage Two',
        'plan' => 'Next, you will Desecrate the Internet. This will cause countless hordes of Computer Programmers to flock to you, begging to do your every bidding. Your name will become synonymous with Dear God No, as lesser men whisper your name in terror.',
    ),
    array(
        'stage' => 'Stage Three',
        'plan' => 'Finally, you will Reveal to the World your Needlessly Big Weather Machine, bringing about an End to Sanity. This will all be done from a Fake Mountain, an excellent choice if we might say. These three deeds will herald the end, and the citizens of this planet will have no choice but to elect you their new god.',
    ),
);
?>

<?php if (  isset($_POST["password"])==FALSE) : ?>

    <form action="wd.php" method="POST">
        <div>Please login</div>
        Password:<br>
        <input type="text" name="password"/>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

    </form>

<?php else: ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if (isset($_POST["password"])): ?>




    <?php if ($_POST["password"] == "secret"):
        ?>
        <?php $_SESSION["authenticate"] = 1; ?>
    <?php else: ?>

        <?php $_SESSION["authenticate"] = 0; ?>
        <a href="wd.php"></a>
    <?php endif; ?>


    <?php if ($_SESSION["authenticate"] == 1): ?>
        <?php foreach ($entries as $k => $v): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?stage_id={$k}" ?>"><?php echo $entries[$k]['stage'] ?></a>

        <?php endforeach ?>
        <form method="POST">
            <button name ="stop"> Stop </button>

        </form>
        <?php if (isset($_GET["stage_id"])): ?>

            <p><?php echo $entries[$_GET["stage_id"]]['stage']; ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $entries[$_GET["stage_id"]]['plan']; ?></p>




        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php
        if (isset($_POST["stop"])):
            session_destroy();
            ?>  
        <?php endif; ?>
<?php else: ?> 

        <form action="wd.php" method="POST">
            <div>Please login</div>
            Password:<br>
            <input type="text" name="password"/>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

        </form>
        <?php echo "invalid password"; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the original question, but you really shouldn't be opening and closing those `<?php ?>` tags in each new line you're writing as this will slow down execution. If you re-open it right afterwards, just don't close it !

Comment: By 'back to the main page' are you referring to the login form?

Comment: You need to check the session variable at the beginning. If they're already authenticated, you don't need to check for the password or display the login form.

Comment: @ZougenMoriver, back to the login form.
Bartdude 10x for the tip.

So far, I'm still trying to understand the PHP mechanism, and it is a little bit tricky. I will reply as soon as I manage to make it work, or when I'll have another question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();  //start the session

function loginForm($url) //gets back the login form
{
    $res = '<form action="'.$url.'" method="POST">
        <div>Please login</div>
        Password:<br>
        <input type="text" name="password"/>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

    </form>';

    return $res;
}

function showError($message)
{
   echo "<p class='error'>".$message."</p>";
}

function login($password) //handles the login
{
    $_SESSION['authenticate'] = ($password == 'secret');
}

function logout() //handles the logout
{
    unset($_SESSION['authenticate']);
}

function isAuthenticated() //returns if someone is authenticated
{
    return isset($_SESSION['authenticate']) && $_SESSION['authenticate'];
}

if(isset($_POST['password']) //if there is a new password, you can try to login
    $error = login($_POST['password']);

if(!isAuthenticated()) //if someone isn't authenticated you can show the login form, else show the rest
{
    echo loginForm("wd.php");
    if($error) showError("Wrong password!");
}
else{
    echo "logged in";
}
```

have a look at this, its a good habit to use functions or even go for OOP. your code will get more reusable etc.

Answer (score 0):

First, reorganize your code. You have to much PHP and HTML mixed to keep good readability. First, do all PHP treatments. Then display HTML with the minimum of PHP within it.

For the bug, understand that each time the page is loaded, you will test $_POST["password"] == "secret" and so rewrite $_SESSION["authenticate"] each time.